# Is there a generic way to remove a subfolder from a URL regardless of where it's located (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I'm wondering if there is a single method that would remove `sub` from any of these URLs:

1. `http://www.first.com/a/sub/`
2. `https://second.org/bob/slob/sub/`
3. `http://www.third.me/sub/`

Comment: All those hosts are served from the same directory/config/vhost?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point of what I'm wanting to know. Basically, I'm wondering if there's a snippet of .htaccess code that could be dropped into any .htaccess file to get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942892/is-there-a-generic-way-to-remove-a-subfolder-from-a-url-regardless-of-where-its?noredirect=1#comment65241059_38942892), try the following:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/sub/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L]
```